# Ubuntu Black Screen

Tags: installation, boot, graphics

I am trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 64bit on my new ASUS Machine. My graphics card in an Intel HD Graphics 4000 card. I am trying to install Ubuntu but when I boot with flash drive and click install, the screen just goes black. I tried replacing quiet splash with nomodeset and radeon.modeset=0 but nothing works. I am also confused because when I click to edit there are only like 3-4 lines of code. Should there be more? Cntl+x does not do anything. If I hit F10, it just goes back to the black screen. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: I have tried all of those solutions, none worked

Comment: Lots of reports that that card is not working in 13.04. You can try 12.10 or 12.04 or try another graphics card. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/295227/black-screen-on-startup-ubuntu-13-04-intel-hd-4000